# How to make a redirect view jump to a section in django

Tags: django

so I have a section in my templates:

```
<div id='comments'>Comments go here</div>
```

now I want my django redirect function to redirect to this page and jump to this div id.

```
return redirect('post_detail', post.slug)
```

Where do I put in `'/#comments'` to make it jump there on redirecting

Answer (score 4):

```
redirect (reverse('post_detail', post.slug) + '#comments')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem a little while back and wrote a blog post about how I solved it. You can check it out here:

https://engineertodeveloper.com/how-to-route-back-to-specific-sections-on-a-page-in-django/

Comment: Your site is hacked