# After clicking the like button I got redirecting to the top of the page, not sure why?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have like and dislike for the article. Like and dislike is working perfectly, but the only problem is when I like the article I stay on the same page, I got redirected to the top of the page. All I want is to stay not only on the page but also on the same position of the page. All my articles have images so to read the entire article we have to scroll down and then the like button is at the end of the article. Here are some details.

### post_detail page(like button)

```
<form action="{% url 'like_post' single_post.category.slug single_post.slug %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                        <button type="submit" name="like_btn" value={{single_post.id}} class="ui red button like_btn" >
                            <i class="heart icon"></i> Like ({{single_post.total_likes}})
                        </button>
                    </form>
```

### urls.py

```
path('<slug:category_slug>/<slug:post_slug>', views.post_detail , name="post_detail"),
path('like/<slug:category_slug>/<slug:post_slug>', views.like_post, name="like_post")
```

### post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/post_image/%Y/%m/%d/', default="../static/images/pp2.jpg")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='post_likes')
    description = FroalaField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail", args=[self.category.slug, self.slug])  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

### views.py

```
def like_post(request,category_slug, post_slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('like_btn'))
    liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id = request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        liked = True
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[category_slug, post_slug]))
```

Comment: I believe you should send the POST request via ajax method without submitting the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `id="redirect_here"` to your form tag and after posting you set a redirect to the page you want to redirect (in this case the same page). At the end of your redirect you add `#redirect_here`.

You can read here:
[Scroll to a specific Element Using html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739126/scroll-to-a-specific-element-using-html)

Comment: Yes I thought about that too first but I don't how to implement it in views.py file. I cannot change the redirect URL. Please show me how to implement it in my views.py

Comment: maybe this helps you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788600/how-to-make-a-redirect-view-jump-to-a-section-in-django